# Finding most distinct elements in a set

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Say we have a perfume shop that has 100 different perfumes.

Let's say 10,000 customers come in an rate each perfume one through five stars.

Let's say the question is: "how to best construct a pack of 5 perfumes so that 95% customers will give a 4+ star rating for at least one of them"

How to do this algorithmically?

NOTE: I can see that even the question isn't properly formed; there's no guarantee that such a construction even exists. There is a trade-off between 2 parameters.

NOTE: Also, (and this makes the perfume analogy becomes slightly artificial), it doesn't matter whether we get one good match or three good matches.  So {4.3, 0, 0, 0, 0} would be equivalent to {4.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2} -- in both cases the score is 4.3.

Let's say for the purpose of argument that perfumes 0-19 are sweet, perfumes 20-39 are sour, etc (sim. salt, bitter, unami)

So there would be very high crosscorrelation between 0-19.

If you modelled this with 100 points in space, then 0-19 would all attract each other very strongly, they would form a cluster.

Similarly you would get 4 other clusters for the other four tastes.

So from just one metric, we have separated out 5 distinct flavours.

But does this technique extend?

π

PS just giving the names of related techniques would be very helpful, as this would allow me to Google for further information.  So any answer that just restates the question in industry accepted terminology would be useful!

Comment: Pick one 4-5 star perfume, pick 4 1-3 star perfumes, repeat. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like [Maximum coverage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem). Where k=5, customers are "elements", and customers giving a 4+ star rating for some perfume form a "set".

Comment: You are asking for an algorithm but you have not tried to create one yourself. This is no better than "plz send teh codez".

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm should find a solution to the problem:

1. Order the perfumes by the number of customers giving a 4+ rating
2. Choose the first perfume not concidered yet from the list
3. Delete the ratings from the customers now satisfied.
4. Repeat the process for perfumes 2 - 5 in the pack.

Backtrace when neccessary to obtain a selection satisfying the criterion.

Answer (score 1):

The true problem is NP-hard, but you can make use of a greedy algorithm:

1. Let C be the whole of your customers.
2. Assign to each perfume a coverage given by the number of customers in C that gave 4+ to each perfume
3. Sort by descending coverage. If C is empty and all coverages are zero, choose a perfume at random (actually, if C is nonzero but < 5% of the original, your requisite is met)
4. Remove from C all **customers** (not ratings) satisfied by the perfume just chosen
5. Repeat from 2 unless you already have 5 perfumes.

This automatically takes care of taste clustering: a customer giving high marks to sweet perfumes will be satisfied by the most voted sweet perfume, *and* he will then be struck out from C, all his further ratings ignored, and the algorithm will proceed to satisfy *other* customers.

Also, you should notice that even if you can't satisfy the requisite (95%, 4+) with five perfumes, perfume similarity will ensure that this algorithm maximizes both the coverage and the marks - so you might end up with, say, (93%, 3.9).

Also, suppose that 10% of users do not give any marks above 3. There's *no way* that you can 4-satisfy 95% of customers, since 10% of total are at most 3-satisfiable. You might want to build C with customers that actually **did** give at least one 4+ rating.

Or you could change the algorithm and instead of the one in your question, decide on using a knapsack: you want to take home the highest *cumulative* rating. This also raises the likelihood of a customer being satisfied by the *overall package* (as is, he is almost guaranteed to very much like **one** perfume, but he might strongly dislike the other four).